# Enable "Go to definition" menu in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using `VS2012`. I tried to navigate the function definition using the context menu item `"Go to definition"`, but the menu item is disabled.

> How to enable **Go to definition** menu?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but what version do you have? If you place your cursor on the item you want to view and press F12, does that take you to the definition?

Comment: I tries with that shortcut too... It is not working... Then only I saw the context menu, the menu is disabled...

Comment: What version of VS are you using?  Express, Pro, Premium, Ultimate?

Answer (score 0):

Delete or rename (the extension) of the SUO file in the project (root of the directory) and that should correct your issue.
[image]